# Emberjs grunt template compiler

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I am attempting to use Grunt to pre-compile my .hbs templates for my Ember app.  Grunt item being used:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ember-templates

I have gotten Grunt to work just fine, and the single templates.js file is being compiled:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["dashboard/dashboard"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
    helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};

    data.buffer.push("<script type=\"text/x-handlebars\" data-template-name=\"dashboard\"> Dashboard </script>");
});
```

And here is the routes file:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('dashboard', { path: '/dashboard' });
});
```

And here is the index.php file:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{outlet}}
    </script>
</body>
```

However, when I got to the path of localhost/app/#/dashboard, the "Dashboard" text does not get displayed.  Am I missing something obvious?  I tried googling for the resolution, but couldn't find anything.  I did try placing "dashboard/dashboard" as the template name in this.route(templatenamehere), ... but that produced the following error:

"Cannot read property '**ember_meta**' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '**ember_meta**' of undefined"

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help to see the grunt task, but it doesn't look like you're including a reference to the compiled template file in index.php?